# How can I add a style to a form element in Symfony 4?

Tags: css, forms, symfony, attributes, formbuilder

I am working with the formBuilder in Symfony 4:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
    ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
```

I want to add a style to the form:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
    ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('style' => 'margin-right:5px'), 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
```

I do not see the style. It is not added to the field...

Comment: Well to me you should just add a css class like you did on the first code block you provided : 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control my-awesome-style'). Otherwise you could do it in the twig template : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have twice the array key attr so change it to:

```
    ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control','style' => 'margin-right:5px')))
```